# How do you nest Kotlin tests in packages in intelliJ?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, junit5

I have a new Kotlin project in intelliJ building with Gradle. I am using JUnit5 as a testing scheme.

Initially when writing my tests, they were executable from intelliJ using the green arrow. After writing some more tests, I decided to start organizing my tests into subpackages. As soon as I moved a test into a subpackage, the test began to fail with an error

> No tests found for given includes: [PackageName.FileName.TestName]

If I look at the gradle run configuration of that test, I see

> :test --tests "PackageName.FileName.TestName"

Running this command directly with gradle also fails. If I run
`./gradlew :test` my test runs succesfully. If I omit the package name in the gradle command, `./gradlew :test --tests "FileName.TestName"` it runs succesfully. How can I get gradle to recognize the packagename? Or as a worse solution, how can I get intelliJ to generate the gradle run configurations without the package name?

Comment: You can add new Gradle Run configuration without the class name in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Yes, but how can I get this to be the default configuration for running tests, accessible by hotkey and the green run arrows on the sides of tests? The manual changes I make produce a valid run configuration, but it doesn't change these hotkeys. Even when I remove the old configurations, trying to use hotkeys or the green arrows reproduces these bad configurations.